# Do I need to include files that my included files depend on?

Tags: c

I have a C program named coderTest.c in a directory. In a sub-directory, src, I have several files, one.c, two.c, three.c, and their associated header files one.h, two.h, three.h.

I want to use functions from one.c and two.c in coderTest.c. Both one.c and two.c use functions from three.c. Do I need to include three.c in coderTest.c, or will it take care of it's dependency on it's own?

I am using `#include "src/one.h"` for one and two.

Comment: No the compiler knows what depends on what.  Just include the correct file

Comment: `#include "three.h;` in one.c and two.c.

Comment: In the specific translation unit all (and only) headers required for that specific unit should be included. Without relying on the fact/possibility that they are already included by other headers. Equally, don't design any headers that are relying on a fact/possibility, that some other headers were included before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to include three.c in coderTest.c, or will it take care of
>   it's dependency on it's own?

You don't need to include `"src/three.h"` in `coderTest.c`, but this does not mean, that compiler does handle dependency automagically. This header needs to be included in `one.c`, `two.c`  and `three.c`. The last one is to confirm that header's declarations and definitions match with each other properly.

As a result, you project might look as:

#### `coderTest.c`:

```
#include "src/one.h"
#include "src/two.h"
// ...
```

#### `src/one.c`:

```
#include "one.h"
#include "three.h"
// ...
```

#### `src/two.c`:

```
#include "two.h"
#include "three.h"
// ...
```

#### `src/three.c`:

```
#include "three.h"
// ...
```

To prevent multiple includes of same header, use [*header guards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) for each header file individually.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `two.c` and `one.c` properly `#include "three.h"` then the compiler will be able to chain the dependencies together without a problem. If you wanted to run something from `three.c` in `coderTest.c` it would want you to #include it in there as well.

Do your files have the preprocessor directives `#IFNDEF`, `#DEFINE`, and `#ENDIF`in place to prevent duplicate importing?

Comment: The directives should be lowercase

Answer (score 0):

In coderTest.c, include the following:
`#include "src/two.h`
`#include "src/one.h`

In one.c, include:
`#include "src/three.h`

In two.c, include:
`#include "src/three.h`

> Do I need to include three.c in coderTest.c, or will it take care of it's dependency on it's own?

No you don't need to include three.c in coderTest.c, because one.c and two.c abstract it away.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want several ways as long as *visibility to necessary prototypes is provided*.  In addition to where best to include header files, consider  using ***[wrappers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Once-Only-Headers.html)*** to guarantee your header is used only once:

```
 #ifndef _SOMEFILE_H_
 #define _SOMEFILE_H_

     the entire file

 #endif /* SOMEFILE_H__SEEN */
```

Also consider readability.  For example given:  coderTest.c, one.c/.h, two.c/.h, three.c/.h  are as you described:
***1)***  You should include three.h in both one.c and two.c.
***2)***  For coderTest.c,  #include headers of all supporting headers either in the file itself, ***or*** perhaps in a *collector* header: conderTest.h:

***coderTest.h:***

```
#include "./src/one.h"
#include "./src/two.h"
#include "./src/three.h"
```

***coderTest.c***

```
#include "coderTest.h"
```